# Scrollytelling sound restrictions work around

Tags: javascript, css, animation, audio, autoplay

My problem is very specific and can't find much in terms of resources.

I am working on a website that tells a story through scrolling and includes tons of CSS animations triggered by viewport (most likely using IntersectionObserver API) and background video.

Have a look at :

https://www.sbs.com.au/theboat/

the main challenge is finding a way to autoplay audio in the same way I trigger animations with all the browser's autoplay restrictions.

If you look at the link above how do you think this was accomplished?
Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried in terms of code? Please edit your question include any relevant code to get a more favorable outcome from the SO community.

Comment: Thats amazing story! Its simple with jquery [offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/). It can find out, if the div touch top of screen. You could also get any other place on screen using some math. I saw they made also each chapter just playing once. If I scroll back, the sound doesnt play again.

Comment: Cheers for the response, yup it looks like that for some of the sounds while some are ongoing.